# Dividing strings into multiple strings using find/get function in Swift

Tags: string, swift

I have a string that i download from the web so that I can update the information in my app via a website. Is there any way for me to divide that string into multiple strings? Let's say my string is:

```
String = 
"
st1: "String one"

st2: "String two"
"
```

Can i use something like `let mySt: string = find.string(st1) // mySt is "String One"`

If necessary, I'm open to use any other language on my website to make this work (however then it would be more like an http request, which i prefer not to use).

*(if you are wondering what i mean, it's similar to that self-retweeting tweet from a while ago, or ask me and ill try to explain it better ;-)*

Comment: How about using JSON? There are several swift libraries you can use, or you can create your own

Comment: but how would i do that? is there some documentation i can read about it or something? @Antonio

Comment: Just do a google search. JSON has been around for several years, and it's the de-facto standard for remote invocations, along with REST. It's not by any way a swift feature, because it works with any language.

Answer (score 0):

When you download your strings why not just add them to a dictionary or an array and parse through the data?

or

If your the one adding it on the web also why not seperate the strings with a , and call

```
NSString *string;

[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```